# how to make element appear at the spot where mouse clicks in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to start with a blank page, and when the user (mouse) clicks anywhere in the page, a box appears at that location.

This is what I have so far, I made the box hidden and then changed the style by adding an event listener but how do I create another event that allows the user to click anywhere, box appears, then click again in a different spot and another box appears in that location. -- using only vanilla Javascript

Thanks in advance, here's my html/css code:

```
  <div id ="box"></div>

  #box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  }
```

and Javascript code:

```
 var box = document.getElementById("box");
       addEventListener('click', function(){
          box.style.visibility="visible";

      });
```

Comment: This might help: `myOnClickImplementation(event) { console.log(\`screenX:  ${event.screenX}, screenY: ${event.screenY}, clientX:  ${event.clientX}, clientY: ${event.clientY}\`) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get offsetX/Y or pageX/Y. Offset is relative to target element, page - relative to document

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");
   addEventListener('click', function(event){
     box.style.visibility="visible";
     box.left = event.pageX;
     box.top = event.pageY;
   });
```

Comment: + my answer, please

Comment: @Nosyara The OP doesn't have enough rep to upvote yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` to get the cursor position relative to the document top-left corner. Try it below:

```js
addEventListener('click', createBox);

function createBox(event) {
  var box = document.createElement('div');
  box.className = 'box';
  box.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
  box.style.top = event.pageY + 'px';
  document.body.appendChild(box);
}
```

```css
.box {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p>Click anywhere!</p>
```

Also note that if you want to have multiple boxes, it is best to use a class rather than an ID. An ID is meant to reference a unique element, whereas a class is meant to be shared among multiple ones.